# Minimize $\max_i \|(XR^T)_{:,i}\|_2$ over rotation matrices $R$

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, positive-semidefinite

Given a set of vectors $X\in \mathbb R^{n\times d}$, I'm trying to find a rotation matrix $R\in\mathbb R^{d\times d}$ (that is $R R^T=I$) that minimizes the maximum column norm of the product  $XR^T$.

If $A=XR^T$, [according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm), this is also known as the $\|A\|_{\infty,1} = \max_{1\le j\le n}\|A_{:j}\|_2$ norm. (Though I'm not sure if that's a mistake, and it should be the $\|A\|_{\infty,2}$ norm?)

In an case, if we didn't have the restriction that $R$ has to be a rotation, and we were optimizing instead $\max_{1\le j\le n}\|A_{:j}\|_1$, it seems like we could just use linear programming.

So I'm wondering if it might be possible to solve my "quadratic" version using Semidefinite Programming (SDP)?

Or maybe the orthogonality constraint on $R$ is not convex, and we have to try to solve the problem using heuristic methods. Does anybody know if this problem have been studied before and what methods tend to work better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note first of all that the problem is equivalent to finding $R$ such that the maximal diagonal entry of the positive semi-definite matrix $RX^TXR^T$ is minimized. Since the trace is fixed (it is the same as the trace of $X^TX$), you just want to make all diagonal entries equal to each other. The quickest way to do it I can think of is just to run the rotation method in reverse. Take the largest and the smallest norm columns (or, which is the same, the largest and the smallest diagonal entries in $X^TX$) and apply a 2D rotation between them that makes one of the resulting norms exactly right ($1/d$ of the trace). Then put this one aside and repeat with one fewer columns and so on. I believe you'll be able to implement this algorithm yourself, but if you have any questions, do not hesitate to ask. :-)

Comment: Is there a nice way to find the $\theta$
 that rotates the column to a given norm? It seems like I have to solve a quartic equation. But of course it may still be pretty fast.

Comment: @ThomasAhle I do not see an explicit form for the solution. I just kept the equation in the trigonometric form and merely used the bisection when checking that it runs fine (though the combination of bisection and Newton will be even faster and then, if your $n$ is above $20$, the computation of the relevant scalar product of columns will take more time anyway). Just don't compute the scalar products you won't need. The running time is $C(dn+d^2)$, not $Cd^2n$ :-)

Comment: Perfect. I wrote up the solution here: https://gist.github.com/thomasahle/0a53cecd24403b8c3f3634249f4da725 It could probably be optimized to run in $O(nd + d\log d)$ using a heap, but I tend to have $d < n$, so $nd+d^2$ is fine.

Comment: @ThomasAhle You don't even need a heap, just two queues: the columns below the average and the columns above the average (any of the former can be coupled with any of the latter at each step). So it is technically $nd+d$ if you just need to modify $X$. I didn't bother to optimize here because I assumed that you need to output $R$ anyway :-)

Comment: Ah right, nice! I guess it's actually inefficient to build R, since we should be able to apply the resulting rotation to a vector in $O(d)$ time.